# Naming convention for content provider URI

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I have created a content provider "com.example.application" . Now I want to further create more URIs using the same one.

For example, for students subjects, students extra-curricular activities, etc. My question is, do we have a naming convention that when I am adding URI, like

1) is underscore a good naming convention ?
Like "content:\com.example.application\student_subjects"

Or

2) is camel case is a good naming convention ?
Like "content:\com.example.application\studentExtraCurricular"

Please let me know which one is a preferred naming convention.

Comment: The path portion of a `Uri` is up to you. There are no widely-used conventions that I am aware of. So long as it is valid, and it works, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare